# delete record in web page not in the database using laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

i am novice to the laravel.I need to do functionality like click the delete link the data is delete in the web page but it should not delete in the database.I already search in the google but did not get any idea.Can any one suggest for this?

Advance Thanks

Comment: take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: Thanks for your reply shoieb and ronald.I am trying these approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches that you can do:

1. You may add an "enabled" boolean field in the database table so that if the user clicks "Delete" on the front-end, you can just set it to "0" (false). Then filter out the view w/ only "enabled" entries.
2. You may utilize JavaScript for this by setting the it as "visible:false".

Comment: i used this approach i got the result.Thank u Mr.ronald.But i did some changes

Comment: Glad to help. Also kindly upvote the answer. Thanks! :)